# FontAwesome6.Core missing Assemblies

Tags: visual-studio

For some unknown reason Visual Studio 2022 unable to find very common Assemblies System, system.core and more. Looking at SDK I was able to find all missing Assemblies, but Visual Studio 2022 is not happy.
MSB3644 The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not found

Comment: What versions of .Net Framework have you got installed?

Comment: 6.0 I am working on https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtjIdnVOoJXtpZ4zPbePp8HAb5XmLw?e=4VVJeG

Comment: I placed more image at same location I am using Microsoft .NET SDK 6.0.300.

Comment: .Net 6 is not compatible with .Net Framework 4.x. It sounds like something in your project appears to have a dependency upon .Net Framework 4.